# Date is undefined

Tags: d3.js

I am a super new to D3. I am trying to use 'map' to display the data, but it keep saying undefined.
The last command data.map(r=> r.date) keep showing the Arrays of undefined.

d3 = require("d3")

data = d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_US.csv", d3.autoType)

date = data.columns.slice(-1)[0]  // pick any negative number

data.map(r=> r.date)

Result:
Array(3340) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, ....

It is supposed to show the data in each column.

I would appreciate if I can get any help here.

Comment: possibly out from left field (and not knowing d3.js.. it probably is left field),  is ```date - ...``` intentional?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. what do you mean that out from the left field??

Comment: mainly because since I only inspected the code without the knowledge of the syntax, it could possibly be wrong..

Comment: Can you please point out which part is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of your objects doesn't have a date, but rather a list of dates, like this:

```
{
  "UID": 16,
  //...
  "Combined_Key": "American Samoa, US",
  "1/22/20": 0,
  "1/23/20": 0,
  "1/24/20": 0,
  "1/25/20": 0,
  "1/26/20": 0,
  "1/27/20": 0,
  // ...
}
```

We can try with an accessor instead (here with D3 v6):

```
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_US.csv", d3.autoType).then(data => {
  console.log(data)
  const atDate = date => data.map(r => r[date])
  console.log(atDate("1/24/20"))
})
```